# Convert Pandas Column of ISO 8601 Data to Seconds

Tags: python, pandas, duration, iso8601, isodate

I'm trying to convert a pandas dataframe column of ISO 8601 duration data to total seconds. The duration values look like `PT7M7S` which would mean 7 minutes and 7 seconds. isodate 0.5.4 is effective in parsing one string if I use something like `isodate.parse_duration("PT7M7S")`. However, I need to run that same command on a pandas column and have no idea how. I tried `isodate.parse_duration(df2['duration'])` but it returns a `TypeError: Expecting a string`.

### The following code creates a test dataframe:

```
df = ["PT7M7S", "PT7M14S", "PT6M45S"]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df)
names = df.columns.tolist()
names[names.index(0)] = 'duration'
df.columns = names
```

### This is the code I tried but was not effective:

```
import isodate
dur = isodate.parse_duration(df['duration'])
df['duration'] = dur.total_seconds()
```

Ideal output would be to have the column `duration` consist of the total seconds corresponding to that row. So for example, instead of the first row having `PT7M7S` it would read `427`.

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: `dur = df2['duration'].apply(isodate.parse_duration)` should work but it may be quicker to just parse the string to extract the minutes and seconds components and then just perform arithmetic on those extracted values if you have a lot of strings to parse

Comment: Thank you! This does put it in `hh:mm:ss` format and not total seconds but I can work with that. I really appreciate your help. If you'd like to submit this as an answer I can select it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to parse the strings:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'duration': ["PT7M7S", "PT7M14S", "PT6M45S"]})
df[['minutes','seconds']] = df['duration'].str.extract(r'PT(\d+)M(\d+)S', expand=True).astype('int')
df['total_seconds'] = 60*df['minutes'] + df['seconds']
```

yields

```
  duration  minutes  seconds  total_seconds
0   PT7M7S        7        7            427
1  PT7M14S        7       14            434
2  PT6M45S        6       45            405
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It works great when I run it on my small sample dataframe that I provided here but for some reason I get the following on my larger dataset of around 300 rows. `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`

Comment: That means there is at least one string in `df['duration']` that does not match the regex pattern `PT(\d+)M(\d?)S`. We can find out what those strings are using `df.loc[~df['duration'].str.contains(r'PT(\d+)M(\d+)S')]`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `apply` function on the Series `df['duration']`, this would be much faster.

Here is a code sample.

```
In [17]: df['duration'] = df['duration'].apply(isodate.parse_duration)
In [18]: df['duration'] = df['duration']/np.timedelta64(1, 's')
In [19]: df
   duration
0     427.0
1     434.0
2     405.0
```

Note, here is one trick: divide `datetime` or `timedelta` object by `np.timedelta64` with different unit, you can get numbers of that unit for this object.

By the way, if you have `NaN` or missing value, you need to handle them.

Another mention, for answer from `unutbu`, it is only suitable if your data only contain `'M'` and `'S'`. Because [`duration_isoformat`](https://github.com/gweis/isodate) could be `PnnYnnMnnDTnnHnnMnnS`.

Hope this would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution:

```
In [53]: (pd.to_datetime(df['duration'], format='PT%MM%SS', errors='coerce') -
    ...:  pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01')).dt.total_seconds()
    ...:
Out[53]:
0    427.0
1    434.0
2    405.0
Name: duration, dtype: float64
```

Data:

```
In [54]: df
Out[54]:
  duration
0   PT7M7S
1  PT7M14S
2  PT6M45S
```

Explanation:

```
In [55]: pd.to_datetime(df['duration'], format='PT%MM%SS', errors='coerce')
Out[55]:
0   1900-01-01 00:07:07
1   1900-01-01 00:07:14
2   1900-01-01 00:06:45
Name: duration, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```